# instead of "you're in my hair", someone said "you're on my hair", is that right? or different meaning?

Tags: adjectives

https://www.instagram.com/p/B0SVsbHJN5Z/
It seemed a hilarious one, but I just don't get it. If it wanted to say same as  "I love you but you're annoying a little bit", why did it use "on my hair", or it's totally different meaning?

Answer (score 3):

It's a joke.

Someone has taken an old 'Gone with the Wind' movie poster depicting a dashing Rhett Butler (Clark Gable) carrying the unconscious southern belle Scarlett O'Hara (Vivien Leigh) from a burning building and meme'd it to form a joke, albeit a little labored.

[image]

It might have been a little better if the meme was,

> *This rescue would go a lot smoother ... if you stopped standing on my hair.*

Comment: The image is based on the film poster for _Gone with the Wind_: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0031381/mediaviewer/rm3798944768

Comment: Thanks @Shoe. I recognize it now. I guess the follow-up meme would have something to do about not giving a damn.

Comment: @Shoe The original poster has a sort of visual double-meaning for me. The flames are not only physical flames from the burning house but also figurative 'flames of passion'.